# E39 key chip not recognized with another key

Tags: bmw, key

Long story short: wife dropped my e39 diamond key, chip is gone, can't find it. I removed the chip from the plastic key
[image: e39 key]
and put it in the main key and assemble it back.
[image: e39 key]
 Car won't start. If I remove the key circuit (key case and chip only left) the car will start. My guess is that it will only recognize the key circuit if it's near the original chip, chip from one key with circuit from another key refuse to start. Is there any diy workaround for this? Like a reset procedure for the key or something, Im sure the official dealer will ask a months worth of fuel for the job.
Thank you

Comment: These aren't that easy to break apart and assemble into other keys for the very reason they have this security feature in the first place. Can you imagine how much easier to steal cars it would be? Anyway, I'd suggest you call a dealer and a locksmith to get a quote to have the work done. It will save you A LOT of hassle despite the cost.

Comment: Actually I don't see how this makes the car more or less secure. You can start the car with a simple key copy by holding the chip close to the ignition. It simply refuses to start if you attach the circuit to it. All parts are its own

Comment: I am afraid you will have to visit a BMW dealer for this particular situation. They will have to make you a new chip which will be combined with the car. Should cost like 130 euro, atleast here in the netherlands. Also, be aware it will take a few days because they can not do this at your local dealer. This is done by a few official BMW garages. Your key will be re-programmed. I have seen many people trying to do this themselve, but really, it's not worth it. just take your loss :p